# Using Dreamweaver, how can I populate a drop down list via PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu, dreamweaver

I am trying to populate a drop-down list via PHP embedded in HTML.

Here is what I have so far:

```
  <select name="ChapterList" id="ChapterList" style="width:120px;">
    <?php
    $username = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
    $password = "xxxxxxxxx";
    $database = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $host = "xxxxxxxx.mydomainwebhost.com";

@mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to database");
@mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");

$query = "SELECT * FROM Chapters ORDER BY Id";

$ListOptions = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ListOptions))
{
    echo "<option value='".$row['Id']."'>".$row['ChapterName']."</option>"
}
     ?>
     </select>
```

I know I am recieving the expected results because if I `echo $row['ChapterName'];` , the current values I have in the database are listed in the proper order, so why is it when I `echo "<option value='".$row['Id']."'>".$row['ChapterName']."</option>"` my list receives nothing at all?

Comment: Tried adding a semi-colon to the end of the echo line?

Comment: Yeah I added the semi-colon a while back but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post what the rendered html output is? (View Source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... so I solved my own question in a way.

What I discovered was that my php was being commented out via `<--!` `-->`. I merely changed the file extension to `.php` as opposed to `.html`. The drop-down list worked immediately and was populated with the proper values.

But this raises another question... how can I get **inline** PHP to work? My site is hosted with MyDomain. Is there a setting I am missing somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semi-colon at the end of your `echo` statement

```
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ListOptions)) {
     echo "<option value='".$row['Id']."'>".$row['ChapterName']."</option>";
   }
  ?>
```

Note: Start using `mysqli_()` functions as `mysql_()` are no more maintained by PHP team..

Comment: Sorry, I copied from an old version of the file.
I added the semi-colon but still nothing :(

Comment: @JohnnyGamez is your select box rendering?

Comment: Yeah it's there. And if I make a static list of options, the options are listed properly.

The thing is I don't want to list them directly, I need them pulled from the database.

Comment: @JohnnyGamez Ok, so when you fetch and output it from your database what do you see in your source HTML?

Comment: What do you mean what do I see? The list box is there but nothing happens when I click the drop-down arrows...

I tried the query in a separate PHP file and proceeded to `echo $row['ChapterName'];` , which gives me the proper results: **Alpha Beta Gamma Delta**.

Comment: @JohnnyGamez that's what am saying, there's no options in there right? just click `ctrl+u` in your browser and tell me the rendered HTML

Comment: You are not getting me, I need **rendered** html source

Comment: I am viewing the source in Chrome. Is that what you mean by rendered?

Comment: In chrome press `ctrl+u` now from there, see where your `<select>` is printed, and tell me what you see there

Comment: Control+u is doing nothing, neither is command+u (I'm using a Mac).

So I am viewing the source, and under the `<select>` markup is the same thing I posted in the question...

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
  <?php
$form='';
$link = odbc_connect ('databasename', 'username', 'password');
if (!$link)
{
 die('Could not connect: ' . odbc_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully .<br>';

//Query the database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Chapters ORDER BY Id ";
$result = odbc_exec($link,$sql);
$selectbox='<select id=combox name=Chapters  >';



            while($bin =odbc_fetch_array($result))
                {

                    $selectbox.= "<option  value=\"$bin[Chapters]\">$bin[FChapters]</option>";
                }


                    odbc_close($link);
                    $selectbox.='</select>';
                    echo "Select Name".$selectbox;
 ?>
```

this code is working perfectly for me

Answer (score -1):

try to use this

```
<select>
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ListOptions))
   {
$id=$row['Id'];
$cname=$row['ChapterName'];
       echo "<option value='$id'>$cname</option>";
   }
  ?></select>
```

Comment: No semi colon after `$cname`, and `echo` statement, no opening PHP bracket

Comment: yes i submitted it while talking with my collegues so mistake has made

Answer (score -1):

I have correct them just look at once,

---

```
    <?php 
$username = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxxx";
$database = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$host = "xxxxxxxx.mydomainwebhost.com";
$dbc=@mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password,$database) or die("Unable to connect to database");
?>

<select name="ChapterList" id="ChapterList" style="width:120px;">
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM Chapters ORDER BY Id";

$ListOptions = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ListOptions,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    echo "<option value='".$row['Id']."'>".$row['ChapterName']."</option>";
}
?>
 </select>
```

Comment: you have to put MYSQLI_ASSOC then after your $row['ChapterName'] works otherwise not.....